# How to set objective c label with cons char function in c

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to run my function TestConnection(const char) and set the value from it for my label in objective c. Any help would be greatly apprecitated I keep getting this error "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *_Nonull' in xcode.

Here is my c code

fucn.c

```
const char TestConnection(const char *ip)
{
    //char ipAddr[] = "133.131.232.131";
    char *val = P(ip);
    char *valb = "0packets";
    if(strcmp(val, valb) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "noconnection");
        //return "noconneciton";
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "connected");
        //return "connected";
    }
    return *val;
}
```

func.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const char TestConnection(const char *ip);
```

objective c code Viewcont.m

```
- (void)checkconneciton:(NSString*)ip {
    const char *ipc = [ip UTF8String];
    //TestConnection(ipc);

    //below is the line with the error. 
    NSString* xx = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:TestConnection(ipc)];
    _ip_label.stringValue = xx;

}
```

Comment: Is this the _exact_ code you are using?  There may be some mis-spelling.  (checkconneciton ?)

Comment: `TestConnection` returns `const char` and `stringWithUTF8String` wants `const char *`.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how I would fix this @Willeke

Comment: Yes I had some spelling mistakes they are fixed now @ryyker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestConnection` is defined as returning a single character, not a string.

It needs to return a string -- `const char *` -- which can then be used to initialize the `NSString`.